# Адаптивная р:зметка

Tags: css, css3, css-filters

Как сделать верстку для следующего примера?

Верстка состоит из строки, которая состоит из трех горизонтальных блоков. Центральный блок шириной 1000Px, а два других блока боковых должны быть оставшейся шириной от размера монитора пользователя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас все получится с display: flex; и его настройками.

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/4hhkp2kv/

```css
.flex{
    display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
}
.col{
    background: red;
    flex: 1;
}
.fixed{
    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="fixed">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: круть, спасибо!